# .mouseleave multiple elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created several elements with the class "pathelement". now i would like to output a line in the log when the mouse leaves .pathelement **and does not go to a new .pathelement**

```
$( ".pathelement" ).mouseleave(function() {
    console.log("Lost");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .mousemove() function instead:
[HERE](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery.php#:%7E:text=You%20can%20simply%20use%20the,over%20the%20DIV%20element%27s%20box)
You can then check what elements your pointer is over at any time.